# Integrate $\int_C{\tan{z}\ dz}; C: y=x^2$ (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, complex-integration

> Integrate $$\int_C{\tan{z}\ dz}$$ $C$ is the parabola arc $y=x^2$ that connects the points $z=0$ and $z=1+i$.

This is what I've done so far:

- I know that $\tan{z}=\dfrac{\sin{z}}{\cos{z}}$
- And also, separating $\sin{z}$ and $\cos{z}$ in the form $z=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$, that $$\sin{z}=\sin{x}\cosh{y}+i\cos{x}\sinh{y}$$ $$\cos{z}=\cos{x}\cosh{y}-i\sin{x}\sinh{y}$$

So I used these formulas to separate $\tan(z)$ into that $U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$ form to check with the Cauchy-Riemann conditions if it is analytical (to integrate directly).

This is my result of doing this: $$\tan{z}=\dfrac{\sin{x}\cos{x}+i\sinh{y}\cosh{y}}{\cos^ 2{x}\cosh^2{y}+\sin^2{x}\sinh^2{y}}$$

As you can see, to check that using the Cauchy-Riemann conditions will be a tedious step to complete.

Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks in advance =)

P.S. If there is no easier way, what is the best way to derivate that fraction (as the CR conditions needs derivation to work)?
P.P.S. I'll be thankful if you tell me about possible mistakes I made ;)

Comment: May you use the fact that the quotient of (non-vanishing) analytic functions is also analytic?

Comment: I thought about that possibility, because $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ are both analytical. I'm just unsure about it, because (speaking about real numbers), $\tan{x}$ has a discontinuity in $(0,0)$. Just don't know it the same happens with complex variables.

Comment: $\tan{x}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. It is only discontinuous at the points where $\cos{x}=0$, namely, $2k\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$. Same for $\tan{z}$.

Comment: I made a mistake there -- there are discontinuities in $n\pi/2$, with $n$ being an odd number. Just the system didn't allow me to re-edit =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tan(z)$ is analytic along the curve $C$. So we can choose another path $y=x$, which reduce the integral to

$$\int^1_0 \tan(1+i)x dx$$

You can then integrate using usual way (substitution).

Comment: Yes, that's right! I actually want to do this, but I need to demonstrate that $\tan{z}$ is analytical.

Comment: I think it needs to be analytic in a domain that contains $C$ (which it is...)

Comment: @benji You are right about a domain that contains $C$. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I just don't know if there's another way to demonstrate that, or just mention that fact you told me before (div. analytical functions = another analytical function).

Comment: @TX286 yes that is enough (so long as the denominator is not zero)

Comment: @benji Thanks a lot! =)